# how to add bootstrap classes to my model in admin.py?

Tags: python, django

I don't understand why the form that I am creating in forms.py  `EditProfileForm`  to be able to place bootstrap classes in my "edit profile" cannot be seen.

The form that I have in the "edit profile" works quite well,  but when placing the form.py nothing happens, I don't see the bootstrap effect in my template. can you help me to know what happens?

> models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

   phone1=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   phone2=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   fax=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   website=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   socialMedia1=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   socialMedia2=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   socialMedia3 = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   alternativeContact=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0,choices=COUNTRIES)
   address=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0)
   city=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   state=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
   zip=models.CharField(max_length=10,default=0)
   tax_percentage=models.IntegerField(default=0)



   def __str__(self):
       return self.phone1
```

> form.py

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    phone1=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    phone2=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    fax=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    website=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    socialMedia1=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    socialMedia2=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    socialMedia3 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    alternativeContact=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    address=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    city=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    state=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    zip=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    tax_percentage=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
   


    class Meta:
        model=CustomUser
        fields=('phone1','phone2','fax','website','socialMedia1','socialMedia2','socialMedia3','alternativeContact','country','address','city','state',
                'zip','tax_percentage')
```

> admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form=EditProfileForm
    # form=UserChangeForm
    model=CustomUser
    list_display = ['pk','email','username','first_name','last_name']
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets+(
        (None,{'fields':('email','first_name','last_name','image','location','phone1','phone2','fax','website',
                         'socialMedia1','socialMedia2','socialMedia3','alternativeContact','country','address',
                         'city','state','zip','tax_percentage')}),
    )
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets+(
        (None,{'fields':('email','first_name','last_name','image','location','phone1','phone2','fax','website',
                         'socialMedia1','socialMedia2','socialMedia3','alternativeContact','country','address',
                         'city','state','zip','tax_percentage')}),
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't see the classes"? Do you see them in the HTML or do you not see the bootstrap effect?

Comment: I mean the bootstrap effect in my template

Comment: OK, because I think you need to load the Boostrap assets (JS + CSS) and I do not see you do that in your example.

Comment: To be more precise: You need to define those assets in a Meta class within your Admin class. See this for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions-1

Comment: I would have to put the bootstrap .css in the meta of my class inside admin.py. So it doesn't work the same as forms.py because of that change, right?

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand what you are asking. can you rephrase please?

Comment: ok so I just have to put bootstap css inside meta

Comment: yes, and the bootstrap js too. give it a try.

Comment: no, it still doesn't work.
I put:
  css={
             "all": ("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ",)
         }
js={
             "all": ("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js ",)
         }

Comment: there is no "all" for the JS part. please make sure you use the correct syntax